# PHP select row from db where ID is found in group of IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 employers IDs: 1, 2 and 3. I am generating tasks for each one by adding a line in database and in column "for_emp" I insert IDs I want to assign this task for and could be all 3 of them separated by comma. So let's say I got a task and "for_emp" is "1,2,3", the employers IDs. If I would like to select all tasks for the ID 2, will I be able to select from the row that has "1,2,3" as IDs and just match "2" there ? If not, how do you suggest I insert my emp IDs into one row in database ? The db is MySQL.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. SO, if I use a relation table how can I display data into my grid with Task id, task name, assigned employers ? I would like to display like this in one row: 1 | Test task | Emplpoyee 1, Employee 2, Employee 3. I mean I have to get them names and put it as a single column for displaying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it like that, you should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database.

What you want to do is have a table such as `task`, and then `task_assignee`. `task_assignee` would have fields `task_id` and `user_id`. If a task has eg. three assignees (IDs 1, 2 and 3), then you'll create three rows in the `task_assignee` table for that one `task`, like this:

```
+--------+---------+
|task_id | user_id |
+--------+---------+
|   1    |    1    [
|   1    |    2    [
|   1    |    3    [
+--------+---------+
```

Then it's just a simple matter of querying the `task_assignee` table to find all tasks that are assigned to a given user.

Here's an example of how to get all the tasks for user_id 2:

```
SELECT t.* FROM task AS t INNER JOIN task_assignee AS ta WHERE ta.user_id = 2
```

EDIT.

Just as a related note, even if you didn't do it the right way (which I described in my answer previously), doing it with hacks such as `LIKE` would still be far from the optimal solution. If you did store a list of comma-separated values, and needed to check if eg. the value 2 is in the list, you could use the MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` function:

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, for_emp)
```

But you shouldn't do this unless you have no choice (eg. you're working with someone's shitty DB design), because it's way more inefficient and won't let you index the the employee ID.

Comment: The problem is when I want to list all task with the details. I need to SELECT all tasks and for each task row I would need to get every employer entry for this task in the task_assignee so that I will end up with Task ID | Employer name 1, Employer name 2, Employer name 3 | Task description | Due date. So, when I select the task row, I need a way to add those 3 employer's names into one column for display. I hope you understand what I am trying to say. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have two (good) choices. The first way is to just JOIN the users like `SELECT t.*, u.* FROM task t INNER JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.task_id = t.id INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = ta.user_id`. The downside of this method is that you also get duplicate rows for tasks if they have more than one assignee, but it's simple enough to just parse the required data once. The second way is to first find all the tasks you want, and then a second query to fetch all the users for those tasks, eg: `SELECT u.* FROM user u INNER JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.user_id = u.id WHERE ta.task_id IN (TASK_IDS)`

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE for_emp LIKE '%2%';
```

However, be aware that that would also match employers 12, 20, 21 etc; so take care if you expect you might end up in double-digits.

However, the other answers about renormalising your database are definitely preferable.

Comment: If it has to be done this way (which it shouldn't if the data is properly normalised), then SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE CONCAT(',',for_emp,',') LIKE '%,2,%'; or SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE for_emp LIKE '2' OR for_emp LIKE '%,2,%' OR for_emp LIKE '2,%' OR for_emp LIKE '%,2';

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Create a **relation table** with two fields: `employee id` and `task id`. If one task should be assigned to three employees, insert three rows in the relation table.

You then use `JOIN` to join the task, employee and relation tables.

Answer (score 0):

then its no proper relation...

I would suggest a "mapping table" for the n:m relation

```
employee
  id

task
  id

employeetask
  task_id
  employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a table for your employers. Insert your three rows in it.

Then make a table for mapping tasks to employers. If a task is assigned to three employers, insert three rows into this table. This is basic entity-relation work.

Answer (score 0):

I would make 2 different tables.

1 with employees, and 1 with tasks.

then make another table which combines the two tables, I will call it Assigned Tasks.

Then in assigned tasks I make a assigned id, a employeenumber which is a FK to the employee table and a taskid which is a FK to the Tasks table.

If an employee has more than 1 task. Just insert another row in the assigned table. ;)

When its about Databases, try to think in solo entities! Combining those entities is able in antoher table.

sql example:

Select * from Assignedtasks where employeeID = 1 will give you all his/her tasks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LIKE '%,2,%'` clause in your SELECT statement.

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table where for_emp LIKE '%,2,%'
```

However performance of such non-sargable queries is usually quite bad.

I would suggest that you insert a row each for each employee who is assigned to the task using a separate `TASK_EMPLOYEE_MAPPING` table with `taskId, employeeId` as a composite primary key.

With such a design, your query will be

```
SELECT * FROM TASK_EMPLOYEE_MAPPING WHERE employeeId = '2'
```