# help in sql command .. i want list names which have defined id s

Tags: sql

i have table consist of columns : id,name,job

and i have row stored with this data :

```
id: 1
name : jason
job: 11,12


id: 2
name : mark
job: 11,14
```

i want write sql command to fetch names which have value "14" stored in job column only from this table

so how i do that ?

thanks

Comment: Your job column violates first normal form (by using a non-scalar type) and now you are paying the price: you can't write what should be the simplest query against the data! Solution: normalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(14, job)
```

But that is really not the correct way. The correct way is to normalize your database and separate the `job` field into its own table. Check this answer for extra information:

[PHP select row from db where ID is found in group of IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870878/php-select-row-from-db-where-id-is-found-in-group-of-ids/3870914#3870914)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM   
       MyTable
WHERE 
       job LIKE '14,%' OR job LIKE '%,14' OR job LIKE '%,14,%'
```

EDIT: Thanks to onedaywhen

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM   
       MyTable
WHERE 
       (',' + job + ',') LIKE ('%,14,%')
```

Comment: Ideally you'd be able to expresses this with one predicate: not only are you using three, you've missed a case (`job = '14'`). Try: `WHERE (',' + job + ',') LIKE ('%,14,%');`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing multiple job ids in the same field. You want to normalise your data model. Remove the 'job' column from your names table, and have a second JOB table defined like this:

```
id | name_id | job_id

 1    1         11
 2    1         12
 3    2         11
 4    2         14
```

where name_id is the primary id ('id') of the entry in the names table.

Then you can do:

```
SELECT name_id, job_id FROM JOB WHERE name_id = 1;
```

for example. As well as making your data storage far more extensible - you can now assign unlimited numbers of job_ids to each name for example - it'll also be much faster to execute queries as all your entries are now ints and no string processing is required.

Comment: Where did `name_id` come from?

Comment: name_id is what i'm calling the primary id of the entries in his first table - seems reasonble, that, having removed the job column, that table could be called 'name' or 'names' or something.